# How to save data from android application to a server?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I'm developing an app in android using the developers training that can be found at:
http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

I created a registration activity and wanted to know how to save the detail on a server!
The training is based on using SQLlite which is local to the device. But I want to use a server to store/retrieve data in/from.

There is a link in the training about using the Sync Adapter:
https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Is that what you use to send data to database, such as when user register? Or, we do it otherwise? How we do it if not so? A link or tutorial will also be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to do some more of your own research: rails, php, etc. This is actually not an android question at all as you could ask the same question on iOS, windows,bb,etc. Do you own research then come back with a specific question. Also, please read the FAQ.

Comment: Anyone could tell me whether the syn adapter could be used to do so or not?

Comment: @user2599068 given your server implementation is finished, you may or may not need a sync adapter depending on your needs (application wise). In each case, you may use an `Authenticator`. One of many articles describing that: http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/